# InDesign: how to construct table of contents with dots between titles and page numbers

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, typesetting, formatting

What I mean is something like this, which I found on a Word document I've been asked to redesign in InDesign.

[image: Left aligned title with right aligned page number]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Type in the chapter titles line by line
- Insert a <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the end of each line
- Type in the page numbers after the tabs
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> which turns on the hidden characters so you can actually see the tabs in blue
- Select the entire TOC (Table of contents)
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. A ruler pops open which let you adjust the tabs. Click anywhere you wish to position all the tabs (red marker). This marker can be dragged with your mouse of you can adjust the position in the 'X:' field
- Make sure this marker points to the right. Select it and choose the third icon top left (under the 'Tabs' title).
- Type a '.' (dot) in the 'Leader' field
- And a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYUl0yoVEy8

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to put together such a detailed explanation.