# How to create a table of contents with dotted lines in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, table-of-contents

My question is basically [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91771/), except the **Illustrator** version.

I can think of some hackish ways to do it, but I'm thinking maybe there's a proper way to do it, so I figured I'd ask.

```
Chapter 1
1-1. The table of contents should have dotted lines like this..................4.
1-2. Ideally the dotted lines will resize with the text........................8.
    ◇ Some subset of 1-2 where there are no dotted lines
    ◇ Another subset of 1-2
1-3. And we're back to dotted lines again.....................................16.
```

Yes, I realize most people will use InDesign for this sort of thing. But it's not on the scale of a "publication"; just an informational PDF. And Illustrator is what I've got to work with.

Comment: Further to Scott's answer, the Adobe help page for the Tabs panel functionality is here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/tabs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it pretty much the exact same way in Illustrator as one would in InDesign.

Lines should be formatted as: `Text` <kbd>Tab</kbd> `PG#`.
It can often be helpful to add a space on either side of the tab, but that's not mandatory.

Select the text and then choose `Window > Type > Tabs` or 
hit <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the **Tabs panel**.

On the **Tabs Panel**, insert a right-aligned tab after the page number by clicking the area above the little ruler and be certain the `right align` option on the panel is selected.
<sub>(*Any* of the tab alignment options will work — depends upon the desired alignment of the page numbers.)</sub>

Then insert a period (or any other character) into the `Leader` field on the panel...

[image]

It's also possible to add a period then a space or two, just using the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, to the `Leader` field to create some distance between the dots. There is a character limit to the Leader field. But, I don't recall what it is exactly. The image above is just the period as a leader, the image below has a period followed by a few spaces for a leader.

[image]

Illustrator has no TOC generation functionality like InDesign. 
You'll have to manually build any TOC yourself.